# Converting an iOS5 app to be able to support iOS4.2

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, storyboard

I just created my first iOS application using XCode 4.2 .the application that runs on iOS5 only.

I need to make it work on iOS4 as well.

I have a MainstoryBoard and I am ready to get rid of it and use nib files instead.

the question is , once I delete the MainStoryBoard, what can I do to make it go to the first class ? what settings need to be made to make it compatible with iOS4.2?

Thanks

Comment: change the target to 4.2, it should work

Answer (score 0):

user1051935,

storyboards aren't supported in 4.xxx, only in 5.0 and above. To get the first view controller to load on startup you need to modify the appdelegate file to load up the first view controller's nib file in the window. This is going to be more than just adjusting a setting as the way segue's and nibs are handled in 4.xxx is a bit different than the storyboard method in ios5. You will need to programmatically create the segue's between the views as well. I would suggest picking up a good book on ios 4 programming. There are many available and I have found quite a few on discount now that 5.0 is out. That will take you step by step through working with nibs individually, creating delegates and protocols and segueing between views. I started with storyboards myself and worked backwards to the ios4-way pre-storyboards. It probably wasn't the smartest or easiest route, but it is possible. Now that I work with the views in code, I actually like it much better and don't see much advantage to storyboards unless I am working on a very complicated app (structurally). You can still use ARC with the 4.xxx ios base, which is a blessing!

Comment: Hello 
I use the following way to navigate between nib files :
class *c = [[class alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
[self presentModalViewController:c animated:YES];

I have put this in the function "didFinishLunchingWithOptions" but I get a syntax error saying "No Visible @interface for 'MyProgramAppDelegate' declares the selector 'presentModalViewController:animated:'"
is this the correct way of implementing it ? or do you have any other suggestions ?
thanks

Comment: Only view controllers can present other view controllers.  You want `[[self window] setRootViewController:c];`  You may need to follow this with `[[self window] makeKeyAndVisible];`, which turned up in my automatically generated code.  I suggest creating a new blank project without storyboards, just to poke through it and see how and where it initializes things.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @MySpecialPurpose is the necessary first step for iOS 4.2 support.  However, may I assume you are doing supporting that version so your app can run on second and third generation iPhones and iPod touches?  If so, you will also have to compile for the **armv6** processor on those devices, and update your capabilities.

In your **Build Settings**, find **Architectures** and add **armv6**, like this.  You may find that your existing value is **armv7**, or that it is **$(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT**.  Whichever of those is present, leave it.

[image: XCode build settings for architectures]

Also go to your **Info.plist**.  You may find an array called **Required device capabilities**.  If it includes the string **armv7**, delete that item.

[image: XCode Info.plist settings for Required device capabilities]

These changes are needed as of XCode 4.3.2.  Future versions of XCode and the iOS SDK may add other default project settings that have to be rolled back to work on older devices.